# Kendo datasource is not populating into the grid

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am new to the kendo framework, i would appreciate your help and will provide more details if required.

I am getting empty grid, i dont know what changes are required to populate into the grid.

### Webservice json string

```
{"items":[{"id":1,"publisherName":"Srini","active":false},{"id":2,"publisherName":"Ram","active":false}]}
```

### Kendo Html Code

```
<!-- JAVASCRIPT FILES -->
<script src="../bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="../jquery/plug-ins/colorbox-modal/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
<script src="../jquery/plug-ins/colorbox-modal/colorbox.js"></script>
<script src="../jquery/plug-ins/jquery.placeholder.js"></script>
<script src="../jquery/plug-ins/jquery.jOrgchart.js"></script>      

<script src="../bootstrap/js/bootstrap-prettyCheckable.js"></script>    
<script src="../bootstrap/plug-ins/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>   
<script src="../bootstrap/plug-ins/bootstrap-switch.js"></script>
<script src="../bootstrap/js/bootstrap-downloadFile.js"></script>
<script src="../bootstrap/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
<!-- Kendo UI Web combined JavaScript -->
<script src="../kendoUI/js/kendo.web.min.js"></script>      



<div id="example">
        <div id="grid"></div>

        <script style="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function () {
                var BASE_URL = "",

                    dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                        dataType: "jsonp",
                        transport: {
                            read:  {
                                url: "http://localhost:8080/wad/admin/searchPublishers.htm",
                                type: "GET",
                                cache: false
                            },
                            update: {
                                url: BASE_URL + "http://localhost:8080/wad/admin/updatePublisher.htm"
                            },
                            create: {
                                url: BASE_URL + "http://localhost:8080/wad/admin/addPublisher.htm"
                            },
                            parameterMap: function(options, operation) {
                                if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                                    return {models: kendo.stringify(options.models)};
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        batch: true,
                        pageSize: 20,
                        schema: {
                              model: {
                                  id: "id",
                                  fields: {
                                      id: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                                      publisherName: { validation: { required: true } }
                                  }
                              },
                            data: "items",
                            total: "items.length" //total amount of records. This is needed for paging
                        }
                    });

                $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                    dataSource: dataSource,
                    pageable: true,
                    height: 550,
                    toolbar: ["create"],
                    columns: [
                            { field: "publisherName", title: "Publisher", width: "130px" },
                            { command: ["edit"], title: "Actions", width: "150px" }
                        ],
                    editable: "inline"
                });
            });
        </script>
    </div>
```

Comment: Are you sure that the JSON string gets to the browser?

Comment: Yes i checked the browser it is getting the string.

Comment: What is `searchPublishers.htm` in your Read url??

Comment: Your code works fine, see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/pavtn0my/. If you get an empty grid you should check in the console of the browser that there are no errors and you actually get what you think. Try isolating the code and removing all the unnecessary JavaScripts not needed for this code.

Comment: Thank you very much, what is "op" in the function(op)?

Comment: Hey, that is only parameter `op` used to assign result when function get success...

Comment: Hi Parthiv,Why it is not working when i give something like  read:  {
                                    url: "http://localhost:8080/wad/admin/searchPublishers.htm",
                                    type: "GET",
                                cache: false,
         dataType: "json"
                                }

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

Put your `dataType` in your `transport` like this,

If you use Cross origin then only you have to use `jsonp` otherwise use `json`.

```
  dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({

                        transport: {
                            read:  {
                                url: "http://localhost:8080/wad/admin/searchPublishers.htm",
                                type: "GET",
                                cache: false,
                                dataType: "json"
                            }});
```

Comment: What makes you think that it is a JSONP? What user shows as return string is plain JSON.

Answer (score 0):

if you are gettting json string than replace  line of code dataType: "**jsonp**" to 
dataType: "**json**"

you may use read function as below

```
transport: {
      read: function(options) {
        $.ajax( {
          url: "your url",
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(result) {
            options.success(result.items);
          }
        });

      },
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can post your data with some parameter while reading data and get the result and assign to grid.

```
transport: {
                read: function(options) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "http://sdk.domain.com/services/general.asmx/GetPendingActions",
                        data:  "{'sUsername':'admin@mail.com','sPassword':'13123','sUserID':'1539','sClubID':'1'}",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (result) {
                            options.success(result);
                        }
                    });
                }
            },
```